# update-help in powershell failed while installing oel8 using vagrant in windows10

Tags: windows-10, powershell, vagrant

i am following http://yum.oracle.com/boxes/ and
λ  vagrant init oraclelinux/8 https://oracle.github.io/vagrant-projects/boxes/oraclelinux/8.json
5
Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

```
The version of powershell currently installed on this host is less than
the required minimum version. Please upgrade the installed version of
powershell to the minimum required version and run the command again.

  Installed version: N/A
  Minimum required version: 3
```

[vigrant can not install oracle vm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdMbd.jpg)

now with PS: update-help

[update-help failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzFsv.jpg)

[ps7 installed still](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8NXT.jpg)

EDIT: how can we access https://container-registry.oracle.com/ords/f?p=113:1:852254266753:::1:P1_BUSINESS_AREA:7&cs=3D3zoF-7YgnVneOWGZ5RB7_EzRc_SLtAb0tRhW8nuA-Py4kYUuA4lpEi1Twf-3-UV66aB6fxFZnIBpy14QRfKyw ?

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed the latest Powershell version from github? https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v7.1.3

Comment: yes. still the same.

Comment: do we need this git also after vagrant installations https://github.com/oracle/vagrant-projects

Comment: are you sure that the installer is finding ANY version of PoSh? that looks like a very poor installer error msg triggered by not finding powershell at all. _try to confirm that the account used for the install really can see & run the `pwsh.exe` file._

Comment: @Lee_Dailey within powershell i get ` pwsh -version
PowerShell 7.1.3`

Comment: @CADENTIC - is that while in the account that is in use when the error msg shows up? it's possible that the account in use at that time has no access to the file OR that it doe snot have the file on its path.

Comment: i was using cmder at that time. it was working in powershell. but it did not work with cmder. https://cmder.net/